# Rosie the Riveter and "We Can Do It!"

Tags: world-war-two

I have read that *Rosie the Riveter* is a symbol of the American woman who worked in factories instead of men during the Second World War.

She appears to be associated with the slogan “We Can Do It!” Is this expression still in use nowadays? I mean, do ordinary (American, in particular) people know who is it? Does it preserve its meaning?

Comment: That's somewhat of a cultural question, not really a language question. But yes, many people learn about it in school, just general WWII history or maybe feminist history. You'd have to be pretty old to know about it from the original ads though.

Comment: I'm in the U.S., and I think my teenagers would recognize the image posted in the answer below as being from WW II, but I'm not sure they would know the name *Rosie the Riveter.*

Comment: I agree with JLG - adults are likely to recognize the phrase, but youngsters?  Not so much.

Comment: What is the expression and what is its meaning? Please flesh out your question.

Comment: Most American teenagers don't know what World War 2 was, never mind who Rosie the Riveter was. :-)

Comment: I have edited the question slightly to emphasize its link to the "We Can Do It!" expression.

Comment: Times change. I recognize Rosie as an iconic figure, but I don't necessarily think of her when I hear the phrase, "We can do it!" As a matter of fact, if I'm ever needing to recall or dispense such inspiration, I'm more likely to mutter "You can do it!" – rather than "We can do it!" – in a thick Romanian accent, thinking about how Béla Károlyi urged on Keri Strug at the 1996 Olympics. (2:22 - 2:42 of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZRYiOa5lM8), if you want to hear it for yourself).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh yes, [Rosie the Riveter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosie_the_Riveter) is certainly well recognized in North America these days. [This image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:We_Can_Do_It!.jpg) is iconic:

[image]

and, although frequently associated with Rosie the Riveter, I'm surprised to learn in my research on these linked pages that she is not in fact a representation of Rosie the Riveter.

You ask about Rosie the Riveter as an *expression*. It isn't an expression at all but a cultural icon. It was also a [hit song from 1942](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CQ0M0wx00s). The "We Can Do It!" expression in this image is associated *today* with Rosie. In a Google search for "We can do it" all the top hits are either to Rosie the Riveter directly, or indirectly via the poster. So "We Can Do It!" is an expression that has probably become bound to Rosie the Riveter.

Rosie the Riveter, and this image and expression in particular, are widely recognized in the US precisely because of the [cultural products](http://syracuseculturalworkers.com/poster-si-se-puede-rosie-riveter) that come from that country containing Rosie's image/mythology. In remote northern Canada we're well acquainted with her, too, and I've seen the poster/notecard/fridge magnet in various urban kitchens throughout the country. However, as other users mentioned, it is possible or likely that young people in their teens and twenties don't recognize Rosie the Riveter nor associate the expression with her or with WWII.

Comment: @J.R. thank you for the edit; it's the first time I've put a picture up here and it looked clumsy.

Comment: In North America or in the USA? Please also explain what the expression means and why you conclude that it is still in use today.

Comment: @coleopterist Rosie the Riveter, and this image in particular, appear, as user bib said in their answer, as symbols of women's power in posters and other cultural products, for example, those sold by the Syracuse Cultural Workers (http://syracuseculturalworkers.com/) where a search for "Rosie the Riveter" brings up this image.

Comment: Also @coleopterist, I know the image is widely recognized in the US precisely because of the cultural products that come from that country containing Rosie's image/mythology. I myself am located in remote northern Canada and I'm well acquainted with her, too, and I've seen the poster/notecard/fridge magnet in various urban kitchens throughout the country. However, as other users mentioned, it is possible or likely that young people in their teens and twenties don't recognize Rosie. Hope that answers your questions!

Comment: Thanks :) From the POV of this site, neither the question nor the two answers mention what the _expression_ is. Is it "We can do it"? Or is it something like "I'm going to rivet this up like Rosie"? Is the expression bound to Rosie the Riveter like, say, "Go ahead. Make my day!" is bound to Dirty Harry?

Comment: @coleopterist, I think "Rosie the Riveter" isn't an expression at all (mistaken wording in the original question). She's a cultural icon. She was also a hit song from 1942 (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CQ0M0wx00s). The "We can do it" of the image is now, I suspect, *associated with* Rosie (but erroneously, since that particular image was not originally a portrayal of Rosie). In a Google search for "We can do it" all the top hits are either to Rosie the Riveter directly, or indirectly via the poster. So yes, "We can do it" has probably become bound to Rosie the Riveter.

Comment: Ah! I see. IMO, if the question had been phrased to centre on the "We can do it!" slogan, then it wouldn't have been closed. Please incorporate the content of your comments into your answer. I suspect that if your answer focusses on the slogan, then this question could be reopened. Thanks!

Comment: @coleopterist - have done so as per your suggestion. Not sure what happens next.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4368/discussion-between-coleopterist-and-jam)

Comment: "We can do it!" is not idiomatic; that's about as much as you can get out of that sentence. Who is we? Culturally, the presumed readers, US citizens. What is it? Culturally, whatever it takes for the war effort. All cultural.

Comment: This would be great for history.SE

Answer (score 8):

Before WWII, significant numbers of women worked in light industry, such as clothing manufacture, but very few in heavy industry, such as airplane production. As large numbers of working aged men were drafted or enlisted, there was a shortage of labor in plant, and in particular, war industry.

Women were recruited to "man" the assembly lines. This was a dramatic cultural shift. The image of **Rosie the Riveter** was coined to both recognize those women contributing to the war effort and to rally support.

She appeared in numerous posters and a film was made as well.

The iconic image of the flexed muscle is still widely seen, currently on refrigerator magnets, as a symbol of female power.  However many younger folks in the U.S. have no idea who **Rosie** was or why her role was significant.

Ironically, many women who worked in factories were displaced as men returned from war. The fact that women had successfully done jobs that previously were viewed only as "man's work" would eventually help women as they sought equal opportunity in the workforce, albeit decades later.

See [this article](http://www.archives.gov/exhibits/powers_of_persuasion/its_a_womans_war_too/its_a_womans_war_too.html).

SUPPLEMENT: Below is a poster with a female war effort worker who is usually identified as Rosie.

[image: proud of rosie]

Comment: Great context +1

Comment: @JAM - Thanks. I own a little seen original poster of Rosie with a male machinist and a sailor that I will try to post a picture of once I get home.

Comment: Would be good to see!

Comment: @JAM The picture is up.

Comment: Neat picture bib

Answer (score 2):

"We can do it" in this context means "we can do a man's job" (riveting, heavy lifting, etc.). A few women even enlisted in the Women's Army Corps (WACs) or the naval WAVES, thereby paving the way for today's women to be part of the modern army.

Comment: I always thought it was more of an "America can do it and win the war" kind of thing, but I am mostly going by my interpretation of the propaganda.  Sadly, the jobs and independence women gained during the war were mostly lost when the soldiers came home.

Comment: @MichaelF: The women were displaced by returning soldiers who had WON THE WAR. (But paved the way for their daughters to get good jobs).

Comment: Uh yes, I'm not disputing the fact but in the long run the female independence achieved in those few years was short-lasting for them.  There are winners and losers in each side